# Hide the bottom Navigation Panel in my application in Android?

Tags: android, visibility, navigationbar

I am working on an application where I have to hide the bottom Navigation Panel. I have search and implement the code :

```
        private void hideSystemUI() {

             View mDecorView =getWindow().getDecorView();

            // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
            // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
```

This is working fine.

Problem : When I open any DAILOG on the screen or when the keyboard pops up, the bottom NAVIGATION PANEL pops up again.

Please suggest, how can I handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 this works,

  public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) //19 or above api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
            //for lower api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); 
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

call this method on ur oncreat.